# What could I use to calculate the sum of the total numberof copies being displayed

Tags: c#

What could I use to calculate the total number of copies sold, i know it'll be a sum() and the only thing I have tried is using the song within the foreach loop but i don't hink that'll work as it will be trying to add some other stuff. Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
namespace Songs
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            //InputSongDetails();
            //Console.WriteLine(InputSongDetails());

            Song[] songs = new Song[4];
            for (int i = 0; i < songs.Length; i++)
            {
                songs[i] = InputSongDetails();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Enter an artist name, or just press return for all artists");
            var name = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
            name = name.Trim();

            foreach (var song in songs)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name) || song.GetArtist().Equals(name))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(song.GetDetails());
                    if (song.GetCertification() != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(song.GetCertification());
                    }
                    var totalCopiesSold = song ;
                    Console.WriteLine(song.copiesSold);

                }
            }

        }


        static Song InputSongDetails()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("What is the name of your song");
            string name = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("What is the artists name");
            string artist = Console.ReadLine();

            int records;
            Console.WriteLine("How many records did it sell");
            while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out records) || records < 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("That is not valid please enter a number");
            }
            return new Song(name, artist, records);
        }


    }
}


namespace Songs
{
    class Song
    {
        string name;
        string artist;
        public int copiesSold;

        public Song(string name, string artist, int copiesSold)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.artist = artist;
            this.copiesSold = copiesSold;
        }

        public Song() : this("my_name", "my_artist", 1000)
        {

        }

        public string GetArtist()
        {
            return artist;
        }

        public string GetDetails()
        {
            return $"Name: {name} Artist: {artist} Copies Sold: {copiesSold},";
        }

        public string GetCertification()
        {
            return copiesSold < 200000 ? null : copiesSold < 400000 ? "Silver" : copiesSold < 600000 ? "Gold" : "Platinum";
        }

        public void AddCopiesSold(int number)
        {
            copiesSold += number;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you want to get `Sum` of all songs `copiesSold` right?

Answer (score 1):

With your code you could just create an integer before your loop and count inside it like such:

```
var totalSold = 0;
foreach (var song in songs)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name) || song.GetArtist().Equals(name))
    {
        //rest of your code       

        totalSold += song.copiesSold; //same as totalSold = totalSold + song.CopiesSold
    }
}
```

For a LINQ solution the following would do the trick with sum, where you tell it you want the sum of every `copiesSold` field inside your songs collection:

```
var totalSoldLinq = songs.Sum(song => song.copiesSold);
```

or to include your filter:

```
var totalSoldLinq = songs
    .Where(song => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name) || song.GetArtist().Equals(name))
    .Sum(song => song.copiesSold);
```

Comment: @Umarfarooq99 divide it by the amount of songs that qualify your filter after your `foreach` loop. You could count those the same way `totalCount += 1`. With `linq` it'll be a bit harder, but since you already have the entire loop setup I would go with the first method anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to find the total number of copies sold, you can create a List of copies sold `var listOfCopiesSold = new List<int>();` Here you can add for each song the number of copies sold using `listOfCopiesSold.Add()` and then you loop through the list and find the total sum and also have the number of copies sold for each

If you want to have more parameters, use var `listOfSongs = new List<Tuple<string,int>>();` if you also want the name of the artist for example

Edit1: From what I see in your comment you want the average, this will be `int avg = numberOfSongs/listOfSongs.Count`